# SQL: combine values of columns into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server 2014

This is my statement now

```
SELECT dbo.Request.RequestId, dbo.Employee.Givenname, dbo.Employee.Surname, Employee_1.Surname AS Expr1, Employee_1.Givenname AS Expr2
  FROM dbo.Request 
       INNER JOIN
          dbo.Employee ON dbo.Request.StartedBy_EmployeeId = dbo.Employee.EmployeeId 
       INNER JOIN
           dbo.Employee AS Employee_1 ON dbo.Request.TargetEmployeeId = Employee_1.EmployeeId
  WHERE (dbo.Request.State = '4')
```

But I don't need the output of the command separated in different columns. 
So instead of this output:

```
|2981  |  Tom   |   Johnsen   |   random    |   name |
```

I want this output:

```
|2981- Tom Johnsen - random name|
```

Comment: which rdbms you are using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1):

use concat function

```
SELECT concat(dbo.Request.RequestId,'- ', dbo.Employee.Givenname, '',dbo.Employee.Surname,'- ', Employee_1.Surname,'', Employee_1.Givenname )
FROM            dbo.Request INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Employee ON dbo.Request.StartedBy_EmployeeId = dbo.Employee.EmployeeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Employee AS Employee_1 ON dbo.Request.TargetEmployeeId = Employee_1.EmployeeId
WHERE        (dbo.Request.State = '4')
```

Answer (score 1):

use  `concat()` function

```
    SELECT        concat(dbo.Request.RequestId,'-',
                 dbo.Employee.Givenname,'-',
                dbo.Employee.Surname,'-',
                Employee_1.Surname,'-',
               Employee_1.Givenname )
FROM            dbo.Request INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Employee ON dbo.Request.StartedBy_EmployeeId = dbo.Employee.EmployeeId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Employee AS Employee_1 ON dbo.Request.TargetEmployeeId = Employee_1.EmployeeId
WHERE        (dbo.Request.State = '4')
```

Comment: SQL Server's `CONCAT` function _can_ take more than 2 inputs.  You are thinking this is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  dbo.Request.RequestId +'|'+ dbo.Employee.Givenname+'|'+ dbo.Employee.Surname ...etc. FROM
    …
```

But typically you'd select the columns and do the formatting in the client